# Caching EJB Home object after looking up

Tags: java, ejb, weblogic

I have a swing application that invokes stateless EJBs (**EJB 2.1**) which deployed on **Weblogic 10.3.6** . The stateless EJB is secured via JAAS. **Web app client** get remote interface by JNDI lookup.
To improve performance, I want to cache the EJBHome so that the EJBHome is created only once at client side. For the same reason I want to cache the remote interface at client side.

The first invocation of stateless EJB method succeeded. After that, every remote method invocation results `javax.ejb.EJBAccessException: [EJB:010160]Security Violation: User: '<anonymous>' has insufficient permission to access EJB`.

My implementation for client side:

```
public class ServiceLocatorUtil {

        /**
         * Cached remote home (EJBHome). Uses lazy loading to obtain its value
         * (loaded by getHome() methods).
         */
        private static MyEJBProxyHome cachedRemoteHome = null;
        private static MyEJBProxy proxy = null;

        /**
         * Obtain remote home interface from default initial context
         */
        private static MyEJBProxyHome getHome()
                throws javax.naming.NamingException {
            if (cachedRemoteHome == null) {
                cachedRemoteHome = (MyEJBProxyHome) lookupHome(null,
                        MyEJBProxyHome.JNDI_NAME, MyEJBProxyHome.class);
            }
            return cachedRemoteHome;
        }

        public static Proxy getProxy() throws RemoteException, CreateException,
                NamingException {
            if (proxy == null) {
                proxy = getHome().create();
            }
            return proxy;
        }

        /**
         * Home interface lookup methods
         */
        private static Object lookupHome(java.util.Hashtable environment,
                String jndiName, Class narrowTo)
                throws javax.naming.NamingException {
            // Obtain initial context
            javax.naming.InitialContext initialContext = null;
            try {

                Hashtable env = new Hashtable();

                env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL,props.getProperty("t3://localhost:6969"));
                env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL,props.getProperty("weblogic"));
                env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS,props.getProperty("welcome"));
                env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, props
                .getProperty("weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory"));

                initialContext = new javax.naming.InitialContext(env);

                Object objRef = initialContext.lookup(jndiName);
                // only narrow if necessary

                if (java.rmi.Remote.class.isAssignableFrom(narrowTo))
                    return javax.rmi.PortableRemoteObject.narrow(objRef,
                            narrowTo);
                else
                    return objRef;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                getLogger().error(
                        "Remote EJB cannot be found. " + e.getMessage());
                return null;
            }

        }
}
```

My usage:

```
public class MyTransactionService {
...
    public String getEJBRemoteData(String xmlTransaction) {
        String xmlData = null;
        try {
            synchronized ("A STRING")) {
                xmlData = ServiceLocatorUtil.getProxy().getDataByXMLFormat(xmlTransaction);

            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            getLogger().error("Cannot send transaction data to EJB remote: Exception: "+ ex);
        }
        return xmlData;
    }
....
}
```

I think this is not because of the caching of remote interface since If I create initialContext before each invocation of stateless EJB method, the exception does not occur.

Here is its log:

```
15/12/17 11:31:02 Executing thread : RMICallHandler-6
15/12/17 11:31:05 Initialized thread name :RMICallHandler-6

15/12/17 11:31:28 Executing thread : RMICallHandler-5
ERROR [RMICallHandler-5] (MyTransactionService.java:707) - Cannot send transaction data to EJB remote: Exception: java.rmi.AccessException: [EJB:010160]Security Violation: User: '<anonymous>' has insufficient permission to access EJB: type=<ejb>, application=RemoteEJB, module=integration-proxy-ejb.jar, ejb=MyEJBProxy, method=getDataByXMLFormat, methodInterface=Remote, signature={java.lang.String}.

15/12/17 11:31:29 Executing thread : HTTPThreadGroup-4
ERROR [HTTPThreadGroup-4] (MyTransactionService.java:707) - Cannot send transaction data to EJB remote: Exception: java.rmi.AccessException: [EJB:010160]Security Violation: User: '<anonymous>' has insufficient permission to access EJB: type=<ejb>, application=RemoteEJB, module=integration-proxy-ejb.jar, ejb=MyEJBProxy, method=getDataByXMLFormat, methodInterface=Remote, signature={java.lang.String}.

15/12/17 11:31:29 Executing thread : HTTPThreadGroup-8
ERROR [HTTPThreadGroup-8] (MyTransactionService.java:707) - Cannot send transaction data to EJB remote: Exception: java.rmi.AccessException: [EJB:010160]Security Violation: User: '<anonymous>' has insufficient permission to access EJB: type=<ejb>, application=RemoteEJB, module=integration-proxy-ejb.jar, ejb=MyEJBProxy, method=getDataByXMLFormat, methodInterface=Remote, signature={java.lang.String}.

15/12/17 11:31:30 Executing thread : HTTPThreadGroup-7
ERROR [HTTPThreadGroup-7] (MyTransactionService.java:707) - Cannot send transaction data to EJB remote: Exception: java.rmi.AccessException: [EJB:010160]Security Violation: User: '<anonymous>' has insufficient permission to access EJB: type=<ejb>, application=RemoteEJB, module=integration-proxy-ejb.jar, ejb=MyEJBProxy, method=getDataByXMLFormat, methodInterface=Remote, signature={java.lang.String}.

15/12/17 11:31:30 Executing thread : RMICallHandler-5
ERROR [RMICallHandler-5] (MyTransactionService.java:707) - Cannot send transaction data to EJB remote: Exception: java.rmi.AccessException: [EJB:010160]Security Violation: User: '<anonymous>' has insufficient permission to access EJB: type=<ejb>, application=RemoteEJB, module=integration-proxy-ejb.jar, ejb=MyEJBProxy, method=getDataByXMLFormat, methodInterface=Remote, signature={java.lang.String}.

15/12/17 11:31:31 Executing thread : RMICallHandler-6
```

As the log info, I saw that the fisrt executing thread (RMICallHandler-6) will initialize an EJBHome and cache it in `ServiceLocatorUtil.cachedRemoteHome` and this thread will does its work successfully. But when the other like RMICallHandler-5 or HTTPThreadGroup-4 .. will throw an anonymous access Exception.

Is there anything wrong with my implementation ?
Any suggestion would be helpful.

Comment: please help me .... ! :(